# Running a query on Access from VB, passing variable or function as query parameter

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado.net, parameters

I am trying to run a query an Access db from VB. The general query which I want to run is

```
    SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE Patient.PatientID = ?
or  SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE Patient.PatientLname = ?
```

I tried using an input box which captured the user input and pass that variable to the query, but that failed.

Then I read about writing a function and using that, however, I keep getting an error which says Function not defined, but when stepping through the code, it seems to work.

Here is my function:

```
Module Module1
    Public Function LookUpNow(ByVal userInput As String) As String
        LookUpNow = userInput
        Return userInput
        Exit Function
    End Function
End Module
```

also here is the query as it currently is

```
SELECT * FROM Patient WHERE (((Patient.PatientLName)=LookUpNow()))
```

I am using VisualStudio. Do I have to manually write a connection string using OleDBConnection or does VisualStudio automatically do it??

```
Private Sub FillBy3ToolStripButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FillBy3ToolStripButton.Click
    Dim Input As String
    Input = InputBox("What patientID do you want to lookup?", "PatientID entry Form", "Enter PatientID here")
    Call LookUpNow(Input)


    Try
        Me.PatientTableAdapter.FillBy3(Me.PatientRecordsDataSet.Patient)
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I am so confused and frustrated. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot remotely (e.g. OLE DB, ODBC etc.) run Access queries that contain internally defined functions (vba). The error you got is totally legitimate.**

You can use OLE DB Provider to execute the query. I'm sure you know how to do this but, just in case, here is some helpful info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d9ew87b(v=vs.90).aspx

some examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.90).aspx